# php apache error message - access forbidden

Tags: php, file, permissions, localhost

when I 7zip a folder with php files on a PC and send it to my Mac, I can extract everything properly etc. But as soon as I turn on the localhost and want to open them in my browser, I get

```
"You don't have permission to access the requested object"
```

Even if I change permissions to read, write and execute for everyone, I cannot access the files in my browser.

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: I have to make sure, did you put the files in the proper folder for the web server? I don't mean to insult your intelligence, but it does happen.

Comment: @dpk2442 He gets 403 not 404...

Comment: Can you access other documents in the same directory?

Comment: @rekire I know. I just wanted to double check, because you never know.

Comment: I can access documents in the head directory - it must be something with the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in your Apache HTTPD config file/.htaccess there is a restriction.

Also, look the chmod of your file, even if the directory is chmod'ed 777.

Try testing on a new hello world php script in your project directory, you will see if you can execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the apache can read the files. For testing porpose you could run `chmod 644 filename` and also `chmod 755 dirname`.

If you played with the server configuration make sure that the server configuration allows the clients access to that path.